# Porting C++ program to OSX

Tags: c++, macos, makefile, g++, clang++

I am currently messing with a Fully Homomorphic Encryption Program based on the paper of Leo Ducas and Daniele Micciancio over here https://github.com/lducas/FHEW.git
With the FFTW3 library installed while running make it compiles perfectly fine. However, when I try the same thing on my Mac I receive syntax errors like:

```
FFT.cpp:28:22: error: expected ')'
res[k] = (double complex) out[2*k+1];
```

I tried it with the g++ and the clang compiler. Both give the same result.

Comment: That's C, not C++. You probably want `std::complex<double>` in C++.

Comment: This is **bad code**. Run away. For one thing, This is not C++ code. A good C++ compiler will reject it. For another, it uses `const long int Q = (long int) 1 << 32;`. That's undefined on some architectures. For yet another, it uses `(1<<29+1)<<22` as an int. This is undefined.